# Build successful but crashes

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.harshil.home.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.harshil.home.myapplication.CustomActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="com.harshil.home.myapplication.LAUNCH"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What is wrong with above android manifest.xml? 
Everytime my app is crashing. I m new to stackoverflow so didnt know how to post so i just copy pasted.

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: what is the error you are getting and when on app open or any event click

Comment: how to add it its so much big and long?

Comment: 9-08 15:46:59.691 3513-3544/com.harshil.home.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

Comment: copy the red font section in log

Comment: 09-08 15:46:59.597 3513-3513/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10060: Read-only file system

Comment: It shows build successful but i get error during starting it

Comment: Okay i noted that directly running the app from android studio,s RUn button make it to crash but when i launch it from inside of emulator it worked fine! Cant understand why that but its working if i launch it from android emulator itself!

Answer (score 0):

It was due to exception button which i created but running it second time from emulator or mobile it works fine! Thanks all!